# Is "Traveling Salesman Problem" still NP-Complete if the shortest path length is provided

Tags: computational-complexity, planar-graphs

Assume a set of points $x_i, i=1..n$ and $S$ - *the shortest path that is crossing all the points* $x_i$ is given. We need to find the order of points in this path. I assume that even if we use simple nearest neighbour like algorithm (with stopping if testing path length exceeds the $S$), we will have a polynomial time solution.
This is some kind of simplified Traveling Salesman Problem.

Actually I am unable to estimate the complexity as I am not sure how to cover the topological structure of set of $n$ points.

Comment: Just trimming searches when $S$ is exceeded won't always help, since it's possible every path of $n-1$ vertices has cost less than $S$. But there might be other ways to use the information from $S$.